# How to access geonode generated "instance ID" from Cycles material?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I generate some instances using geometry nodes, each instance has an `id` attribute.

Here is a spreadsheet snapshot showing generated instances :

[image: Spreadsheet showing generated instances]

My geometry nodes are seen below :

[image: Geometry nodes generating instances]

**I'd like to use this `id` from the Cycles material applied to the instances.**

So far, I've tried using the *Attribute* node, *Object Info / Object Index*, and *Particle Info / Index* - without success.

My current attempt of shader nodes looks like this :

[image: My current attempt of shader nodes]

**Is there a way to access the `id` value from the material shaders nodes ?**

I'm aware that using the "Realize Instances" nodes I could create a mesh with custom attributes - but I need to preserve the actual instancing for complex geometry.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with complex geometries and without realize instances right now.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

spreadsheet:

[image]

shader:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll edit my question to be more specific, but I want to preserve my instances - as I need to have many of them, with complex geometries - so "Realize Instances" is too memory hungry for my needs.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible at the moment without realize instances and with complex geometries. If you would have simple spheres....there are some mathematical workarounds...

Comment: I've created the same setup here, now I'm a bit confused... when I use the _Set Material_ node on the original geometry of the cube, the 8 vertices show values 0.000 to 7.000 for _myID_ - and the cube is colored according to the vertex indices. But when I try to do it with the realized instances, the column _myID_ reads 0.000 for all vertices and so the cylinders (or in my case icospheres) get the color for 0. I switched from the _Index_ node I used originally in my setup to _ID_ like you, but nothing changes. The results are exactly the same, the cylinders stay at the color for 0.

Comment: what version r u using? If you provide your blend file, i will check it out ;)

Comment: so it doesn't work with realize instances and it does work without realize instances!? wow....show me your blend file! ;)

Comment: did you change the output value to float? i had problems when it was on integer...although THIS was/is really weird...

Comment: 3.0.0, and I tried it with 3.1.0 Alpha. Yes, I tried default float at first, then integer and now I'm back to float. No, I didn't say it works without realize instances, no need for "wowing" here. I said it works with the original cube geometry.

Comment: ok, then i don't understand what you did...

Comment: Me neither. By the way, on the original cube mesh it works with Float and Integer.

Comment: as i said...if you provide your blend file, i will give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132842/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-chris).

Comment: @Chris habe im Chat ein Bild und einen Link gepostet

Comment: @Chris I wish this bloody chat would sent notifications that someone posted something ;)