# "Set Material Index" node not working

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

How does the *Set Material Index* node work? I placed it after the generated cone mesh, but it does nothing..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just briefly for further explanation:*

`Set Material` defines a new material for the selected geometry. This node is basically used when a geometry is created with *Geometry Nodes*, because for the geometry created in this way there is no assignment to a material before.

However, if you use an existing geometry (for example, with `Object Info`), then you can use the `Set Material Index` node to apply a specific material from the previously assigned materials to the geometry (or parts of it).

Comment: That's what im trying to do. i want to use an existing material on my geometry

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow I understand. But your existing material will only be applied to the geometry you provide via *Group Input*, but not to the geometry you create inside the *Geometry Nodes* (Cone).

Answer (score 3):

You want the [*Set Material* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/material/set_material.html), not the *Set Material Index* node:

[image]

You might also find this [stackexchange Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263553/111042) helpful.

Comment: but i want to use an existing material on mesh, without "defining" a new one with "set matrial node"

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow -- this does not create a new material; it only lets you reference one of the existing Materials you had assigned to an existing material "slot"