# How do I apply input material to output geometry?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I have a curve that has a geometry nodes modifier applied. I noticed that the resulting mesh has no material. What do I need to do so that setting the material on the input object sets the material on the generated geometry?

Note 1: I can get this "working" using a material input node, but to set the material for this particular object, I would have to go digging into the modifier properties. That's different from how I would change the material for any other object. I very specifically don't want that.

Note 2: this seems to be a duplicate of ["Set Material Index" node not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270048), but there is no working answer there.

Just like that poster, I tried the Set Material Index node, and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I'm using Blender 3.5.1.

---

[image]

(Note that the viewport is in Material Preview mode.)

[image]

Comment: Please add a blend file showing the minimum number of nodes so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: ...just add a `Set Material` node.

Comment: @quellenform, and how do I get the material to be set? Specifying the material in the node is unacceptable. Specifying it as a node input is undesirable, as stated in the question. Please show an example of this approach working.

Comment: This can only be solved with *Group Inputs*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoR1y.png If you create a geometry in Geometry Nodes, it must also be assigned a material in Geometry Nodes. There is only one special case, how you can avoid this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/279168/145249 Here I take over the material previously assigned to the object with a trick, but even this has its limits.