# Same gradient material for each instance (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm having trouble figuring out how to assign a gradient material for each instance in geometry nodes? I have this recursive setup of circles where I want to assign a gradient material that faces the same direction on each instance:

Simplified sketch of what I want to achieve:
[image]

3d viewport:
[image]

Realising instances and trying to assign a material to each index:
[image]

Material:
[image]

Rest of the geo node:
[image]

Hope that someone can help me figure this out :) Thanks.

Blend file: [image]

Comment: Without setting it up myself, can you tweak & apply the setup from this post to your problem maybe: [Set Different Material on Each Instance](http://example.comhttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263517/geometry-nodes-set-different-material-on-each-instance)? To make it easier to reproduce your exact complex GNodes setup, you could share your **.blend** file. You can use this service to upload your file: [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and then copy the link to embed the file to your question (like described here: [Blend-Exchange Help](https://blend-exchange.com/help).

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem or provide additional details to show exactly what you need. The way it's written now, it's hard to see exactly what you're asking for. Thank you!

Comment: Hi quellenform
Thanks for you response. I added a quick sketch of what I want to achieve with the gradient material.

Comment: Updated the question a bit. My problem is still to get the same material instanced on each circle and then to make it face the same direction. I had some luck with using an image material for each instance, but then I couldn't figure out how to make the material face in the same direction ‍

Answer (score 0):

If you don't realize instances then each instance should have its own Generated coordinate space.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) But it doesn't work in this setup, unfortunately.. If I don't realize the instances the whole setup doesn't show in the viewport, and because each instance is rotated the material will most likely be rotated in different directions.